# How to calculate $P(X=x|X=x)$?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $0\leq X\leq1$. Assume that the probability density function, $f_X(x)$, is 1, $$f_X(x)=1$$

How do I calculate $P(X=x|X=x)$? Does it have a value?

Comment: Probability of any event given that event has occurred is trivially 1, no?

Comment: Yes, I agree. But is there a way to calculate it? Just like how $P(A|A) = \frac{P(A\cap A)}{P(A)} = 1$ when $P(A) \ge 0$. Just wondering if there’s a way to do this in terms of PDF.

Comment: I would imagine that it is intuitively the same thing

Comment: But in this case, $P(X=x) = 0$? Sorry I meant $P(A) \gt 0$ in the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, so this argument t would have to be fleshed out. I’m just talking about the intuition

Comment: Yup. I have that intuition too. Just seeing if the probability calculus actually assigns it a value, instead of just basing it on common sense.

Comment: There is a consistent way of defining $P(\cdot | X = x)$. And under such definition, $$P(X=x|X=x)=1$$ holds for almost every $x \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: Mind explaining more about this way?

Comment: This is a much deeper question than the answer "obviously $1$" fails to acknowledge.

Comment: The relevant concept is called the [regular conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability), and it requires some expertise in measure theory.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $X$ is continuous uniform distributed (since it has probability density function that is constant over its support), then : $$\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid X{=}x) ~=~ \dfrac{~f_X(x)~}{f_X(x)}\mathbf 1_{x\in[0..1]}$$